# Has Euler's claim about the mystery of prime numbers stood the test of time?

Tags: prime-numbers, soft-question

On the door of the math office at my school, there is a picture of Euler, and a quote attributed to him:

> "Mathematicians have tried in vain to this day to discover some order in the sequence of prime numbers, and we have reason to believe that it is a mystery into which the human mind will never penetrate."

It seems that his claim is not just saying that the sequence of prime numbers is very difficult to comprehend. Rather, it is saying that the sequence of prime numbers is inherently mysterious, such that it cannot be demystified, and that there are actually reasons for this.

Have mathematicians since Euler made any significant progress in debunking Euler's claim? Or is the sequence of prime numbers as mysterious as ever?

(I know almost nothing about prime numbers.)

Comment: The most important theorem about primes seems to be the one referring to the total number of primes that are less than or equal to a given integer $N$ (asymptotically equal to  $\dfrac{x}{\log(x)}$) But this is about the cardinality of such primes $\le N$  and not about the apparent anarchy of their subsequent formation. And this is due to the infinity of its total set. In the same way one could ask how the primes ending in $7$ are formed. Dirichlet's great theorem has nothing to do with this "mystery"

Comment: We know much about the DISTRIBUTION of primes (the prime number theorem is very powerful) , but concerning CONCRETE primes, we know very little. We know for example not, for ANY of the even prime gaps , whether it occurs infinite many often, we do not know whether there are infinite many primes of the form $n^2+1$ ($n$ integer). We even do not know whther there are infinite many NON-Wieferich primes ?

Comment: And finally, we know no method to construct efficiently ANY not yet found huge prime number with , say , $10^5$ digits.

Comment: To find out a pattern in the prime numbers ( a very very old dream of every number theorist ) seems to be completely out of reach. In this sense, the primes are random , although of course completely determined.

Comment: Important results concerning concrete primes : Every sequence $an+b$ with positive coprime integers $a,b$ , $n$ running over the positive integers , produces infinite many primes , the sum of the reciprocals of those primes even diverges (Dirichlet). It has also be proven that there are inifnite many primes of the form $a^2+b^4$ ($a,b$ positive integers)